# How do you reset a file in Jupyterlite to the original version

Tags: pyodide

Jupyterlite is greate with pyodide in the background but I was stuck trying to reset the files to those that were in the distribution.  How do you reset a file?

Answer (score 1):

If you delete a file, if it is part of the distribution it will be reset.  If it is one you created it will go.

Comment: Indeed. Also only files you write in the current directory are persisted. Files created under other paths (e.g. /tmp/) will always be removed on reload)